# Lookup Value replacement in a text file

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have a CSV File(File1) with Key,Value pair

```
Key1,Value1
Key2,Value2
```

I have a second file(File2) which is not a structured data where I have the Key data(Key1,Key2..etc). I will have to find the Key Data followed by constant (A) in below example and then the value to be replaced with.

**File2 content before replacement**

```
Dummy1  Key1 A Value-Old1 BB C
D2 D3  4   Key2 A Value-Old2 BB C
```

**File2 content After replacement**

```
Dummy1  Key1 A Value1 BB C
D2 D3  4   Key2 A Value2 BB C
```

Any inputs is highly appreciated achieving this through awk or sed

I followed this link to get some place, but my replacement file is an unstructured one as opposed to a CSV file as below
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126485/replacing-the-values-in-one-file-with-the-values-in-another-file-in-bash

Comment: What have you tried? You'll basically have to loop over the positions in the second file looking for a field which is equal to one of the keys.

Comment: Yes there will be space after Value-Old1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind loosing some space characters in the output then you could use some `awk`:

```bash
awk -F ',' '
    NR == FNR { arr[$1] = $2; next }
    FNR == 1 { FS = " "; $0 = $0 }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF-2; i++)
            if ($i in arr && $(i+1) == "A") {
                $(i+2) = arr[$i]
                break
            }
    }
    1
' file1.csv file2.txt
```

Comment: This is the broadly the approach I was trying (I checked for  `{if($i=="A" && ($(i-1) in a))` and conditionally set `$(i+1)=a[(i-1)];` but it wasn't returning the right output. When I run your snippet, it works for line 2 but line 1 remains `Dummy1  Key1 A Value-Old1 BB C`. Does it work for both lines when you test? I'm beginning to think I have a local problem that stopped me getting there.

Comment: @DavePritlove It works for me on Linux and macOS, but I had this problem when writing the code. Did you forget the `$0 = $0`? that is the instruction that ensures that the fields are splited correctly after modifying `FS`

Comment: thanks.  I'd actually used $1=$1 to force a reset of the field separator but just tried with $0=$0 and still get the old value for both lines. In your post, pasted verbatim, I get the old value in line 1 but the changed value in line 2. (Termminal on Mac). Very odd. I'm going to reboot with my fingers crossed.

Comment: Very odd, I still have the same glitch. I might leave it til tomorrow to work out what I'm doing wrong as it's getting late here.

Comment: @DavePritlove You should add a `print NF` for checking if the splitting is done correctly, your input files might have unexpected characters like CRLF or HT

Comment: @Fravadona: Your solution worked albeit it removed the empty spaces at the beginning. Now, I am trying to. get that data printed to another file as output. Thanks for your valuable time and effort for helping me